# how to add a circular ImageView to the left side of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

[how to add circle ImagView to the left side of button similar like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPnxW.jpg)

Comment: please post the code you have tried. otherwise search for RelativeLayout and android circle image view

Answer (score 0):

create a drawable file in project.
Apply it to button in xml by 
android:background="@drawable/your drawable file name"

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/Blue"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="11dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="11dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="11dp"
            android:topRightRadius="11dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Make sure you change radius according to your requirement and color of in Drawable file.

Comment: yes id did that but when connect circle image to the left  of the button circle image hid and button show image did not show

Comment: are you seen pic that i did upload